# AngularJS + Jquery broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm a new AngularJS and JQuery student, and i made a code with both languages and it totally broke . This Jquery i copy from internet, but when i was programming the angularjs code, my jquery animations are gone.

my json code is creating three menu levels, i think it's working, but jquery does not helping me too =/ .

Can someone help me please?

```
    <!-- SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="js/lib/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <!-- PLUGIN -->
    <script src="js/lib/inspinia.js"></script>
```

I'm loading correctly all scripts...
Here is a download for the code. (800kb)
(I didn't make a Plunk because there are a lot of code, i hope you understand me

[Click Here](https://ufile.io/c3210)

Thanks for support!

Comment: Please bear in mind, that "the angular way" does not like the use of DOM traversal as jQuery does. They shouldn't be used together without a good/specific reason to...

Comment: I agree with Daniel. Pick one (AngularJS is better imho), don't use both.

Comment: Ok, i got it... but there is a way to do this? once a member told me to replace all HTTP to HTTPS, and it works well, but this time it is not working... Thanks

Comment: Ok, i will work with only angularjs. Thanks for everyone =)